# Passing Down Complex Objects in GraphQL Mutations / Creating GraphQL Objects with Objects & Arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, database-design, graphql

Say I have

```
type Song {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  numberOne: Boolean
  performerName: String!
}
```

And assume that I can create a new Song like so:

```
mutation createSong($title: String!, $numberOne: Boolean, $by: String!) {
  addSong(title: $title, numberOne: $numberOne, performerName: $by) {
    title
    numberOne
    performerName
  }
}
```

**but**: what if I want to have an extra field, called `Lyrics` which is a large object?

```
{
 "1": {
  no: 1,
  content: "I would go out tonight",
  comment: "What a line!",
  and lots more ...
 },
 "2": {
  no: 2,
  content: "but I haven't got a stitch to wear",
  comment: "",
  ....
 },
 ...
}
```

**I don't want these to be their own GraphQL-Type, since they will only feature in `Songs` and I will never query them directly.** They are also not saved in a separate collection in my MongoDB - I can only get the lyrics via a Song. - I don't know how this would work in GraphQL though?

I also don't know how I would write the mutation `createSong` with an additional `lyrics` field that takes an object: How do I pass an Object into my mutation as an argument? I know how to pass down `Strings` or `Ints` - but how about (JS) Objects?

Or is the idea to make all of the complex data into graphql endpoints? That would seem a bit crazy, since I would end up with lots of endpoints and wouldn't have not very much use for most of them.

Comment: In case you mean _types_ when you talk about _endpoints_ (graphql only has one endpoint usually) then yes, you turn all complex objects into types. Types are almost free (compared to endpoints) and extensively used. Some companies have 5 or 6 digit numbers of types in the GraphQL API.

Comment: I think this is what I mean, thank you. So I am supposed to turn the `Lyrics` field into its own type. My GraphQL wraps a REST API which does not expose the lyrics field directly, so I would need to resolve it like so: `resolve(parentValue, args) {
        return axios
          .get('http://localhost:3000/songs/${parentValue.songId}')
          .then(res => res.data.lyrics);
      }` - is this correct?

Comment: Hmm, but don't you have the song fetched already? Maybe your `POST /songs` that creates the song does not return the lyrics?